# How to prevent window from increasing size

Tags: cocoa

I let my app run into split view mode and quit, then the window height will increase 38pix, it's seems the toolbar's size.

I don't know why this toolbar keeps increasing.

Comment: You quit the app and then the window height increase? Could you please explain it a bit further? That seems a bit confusing.

Comment: @vitormm I have fired an Apple bug on this issue. It's easy to hit. You can also try my steps on the native apps, kinds of apps can hit it.